# People eighty years and up

Tags: single-word-requests, latin, roots

Is there a word for people in the 80+ age group?  I know octogenarian means 80-to-89-year-olds.  Is there a word for people in their 80s, 90s, 100s, etc., inclusive?

Supraoctogenarian?

Comment: I have not encountered any word for people 80+. For me it's very custom that no such word should be invented for that. What if I like to choose only 50 to 70 years old? Or 30+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *old* in general, "superannuated."  Otherwise, you'd have to go with "octogenarian, nonagenarian and centenarian," or possibly, "post-septuagenarian."

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're looking for a generic word like *children*; *teenagers*; *youths*; and *the middle-aged*. There is ***[pensioners](https://www.google.com/search?q=pensioners&client=firefox-a&hs=Hqs&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=oAVrUqa0KuuN4wT-sYDwCg&ved=0CFoQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=613)***, a BrEng expression that includes anyone who is retired, which more or less corresponds to the *over* mid-sixties, but they include, ironically, people who are too young for your criterion.

Personally, I would classify a 75+ year-old, as being ***elderly***. Someone approaching their 80s will be experiencing some of the symptoms associated with aging, and I have, in my mind, associated the elderly with fragility and vulnerability. I know this is not true for everyone, and I'm living in Italy where the average life expectancy is around 82 or 83 for women and a little less for men, but I think that we would agree that the majority of *over 80-year-olds* require some form of medical assistance.

To sum up, there isn't a term which accurately describes such a wide-ranging age group because they have little in common with one another. A 90-year-old is usually experiencing severe problems of mobility and probably experiencing some form of dementia too, so I wouldn't  group them with octogenarians. And those "lucky" enough to past the 100 year-old-mark, generally speaking, have lost their independence and are being cared for (or should be) by family members or as *guests* in nursing homes.

Comment: I see "pensioners" used a lot in BE publications. It isn't used in the USA much, except to refer to folks who are actually gathering pensions, which are a perk that few companies here provide any more(note I'm not your downvoter. Just clarifying a point).

Comment: Thanks @T.E.D.I should have clarified that pensioners is a BrEng expression as you correctly pointed out. Nevertheless, I do seemed to be plagued by anonymous downvoters recently *shrugs*.

Comment: Cheer up, 95-y.o. are only slightly more than 50% likelihood of dementia. (The only one I know does, however, have serious mobility issues. Total mental clarity.)